# Branching of anti-symmetric part of product of irreducible representations

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

This is a corrected version of a previous question (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303060/branching-of-products?noredirect, suggested for deletion), which contained a wrong conjecture.

> Let $V_\sigma, V_\rho$ be irreducible representations of the finite group $G$ and  $ V_{\sigma^{'}}, V_{\rho_1^{'}}, V_{\rho_2^{'}}$ be irreducible representations of $G'\le G$ and $[]^-$ denote the antisymmetric part of a tensor, such that 
>   $$(V_\sigma)_{|G'} = V_{\sigma^{'}},$$
>   $$ (V_\rho)_{|G'} = V_{\rho_1^{'}} \oplus V_{\rho_2^{'}}, $$
>   and
>   $$ V_\sigma\subseteq [V_\rho \otimes\ V_\rho]^-.$$
>   Does then this containment
>   $$ V_{\sigma^{'}}\subseteq V_{\rho_1^{'}} \otimes V_{\rho_2^{'}}$$
>   hold as well?

A simple example would be from group $D_3$ where we have $E\otimes E=A_1+[A_2]^-+E$. In $C_2$ $E$ branches to $A+B$ while $A_2$ becomes $B$. And in deed we have $ A\otimes B = B$

The question arises from a chemical problem, but since this field is completely new to me, I might be entirely wrong. My background is linear algebra some abstract algebra including group theory and a bit of "chemistry style" representation theory.
From physical intuition at least it seems obvious, but I am not sure if it holds in full generality and in case what is the argument?

Any hints appreciated!

---

**EDIT**
While approaching an answer and further dwelling about the issue I like to add some complementary questions:

1. In (at least) all my cases (3D point groups) $[V_\rho \otimes\ V_\rho]^-$ is never empty. Again Physics suggests that there is with a few exceptions in the very cases one peculiar irrep contained. The exceptions are the highly symmetric groups (tetrahedon, octahedon, icosahedron-symmetry and in those (some of) the lowest non-one-dimensional irreps (over $\Bbb R$). Can this peculiar irrep be specified further? I imagine it is some "counterpart" to the trivial one (which is always contained in $[]^+$). Furthermore physical intuition suggests, that it this peculiar representation "belongs" to a rotation around the main/highest order axis of symmetry.

Comment: got a hint (merci@mercio):
"$[(V_1\oplus V_2)\otimes (V_1\oplus V_2)]=[V_1\otimes V_1]\oplus [V_2 \otimes V_2]\oplus W$ where $W$ is isomorphic to $V_1 \otimes V_2$", makes
"$V_\sigma\subset [ V_{\rho}\otimes V_{\rho}]^-$ under restrict to $G'$ to $V_{\
\sigma'}\subset [(V_{\rho'_1}\oplus V_{\rho'_2})\otimes (V_{\rho'_1}\oplus V_{\rho'_2})]^-$
thus $V_{\sigma'}\subset [V_{\rho'_1}\otimes V_{\rho'_1}]^-\oplus [V_{\rho'_2}\otimes V_{\rho'_2}]^-\oplus\
V_{\rho'_1}\otimes V_{\rho'_2}$ (after a suitable isomorphism)"
I kind of get the idea but I'd desperately would need a full valid prove ..